# Getting at a substring of determined format, but undetermined content

Tags: python, string

I am scraping a website (unfortunately in Dutch). I extracted the snippet below:

```
 gewezen op het beroep in cassatie van de Staatssecretaris van Financiën tegen 
 de uitspraak van het Gerechtshof Arnhem-Leeuwarden van 5 juli 2016, nr. 15/01196, 
 op het door [X] te [Z] (hierna: belanghebbende) ingestelde hoger beroep 
 tegen een uitspraak van de Rechtbank Gelderland (AWB 14/7184)
```

I want to get the date (5 juli 2016) and the case number (nr. 15/01196). Since I am scraping thousands of pages I can't have it match an exact string. The date could be any date in this format and the number could be anything. The format of the date is always the same, note that the month name is in Dutch. And the format of the number is either XX/XXXX or XX/XXXXX there can also be extra letters between 'nr' and the number. The number is sometimes between brackets/parentheses and sometimes between commas as in the example above.

So the output should be two lists that look like this:

```
 date=[5 juli 2016]
 casenr=[nr. 15/01196] (or 15/01196)
```

In the above example you see another set of numbers with a similar format (AWB 14/7184). However, I know for a fact that the number I need is always the first one in this format to be mentioned. The date is also the only date mentioned in any of the snippets.

Is there a way to get to this output, based on such loose conditions ?
If they were always between commas, would it be easier ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [regex](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) for this.

```
import re

text = u"""gewezen op het beroep in cassatie van de Staatssecretaris van Financiën tegen de uitspraak van het Gerechtshof Arnhem-Leeuwarden van 5 juli 2016, nr. 15/01196, op het door [X] te [Z] (hierna: belanghebbende) ingestelde hoger beroep tegen een uitspraak van de Rechtbank Gelderland (AWB 14/7184)"""

              # Assuming the number always follows the date
m = re.search("(\d+\s+[a-z]+\s+\d+).*?(\d+\/\d+)", text, re.I)

if m:
    print m.groups() # ('5 juli 2016', '15/01196')

    print m.group(1) # 5 juli 2016
    print m.group(2) # 15/01196
```

Comment: Wow, did not think this would be possible. Thanks a lot ! Loving python more and more.

Comment: @Peter There's a link under `regex` in my answer.it should help.